# Only show integer steps on axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've this graph.

[image: IMG]

I only what to display integer steps on the y axis.
So instead of `[0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]` I want `[0,1,2]`.

Is that possible? I'm not sure what to look for in the official API.

Comment: @Rene: it's [tag:highcharts] (though I'm not entirely sure that tag was there when you left the question). [API link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts).

Comment: @DavidThomas The tags hasn't been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is the `allowDecimals` Boolean:

```
yAxis: {
    allowDecimals : false,
    /* completely irrelevant stuff follows... */
    title: {
        text: 'It\'s the y-axis'
    },
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
    }]
},
```

With [`allowDecimals: false`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PcrDz/1/).

```
yAxis: {
    allowDecimals : true, // though it defaults to 'true' anyway...
    /* other stuff... */
},
```

And the same graph with [`allowDecimals: true`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PcrDz/).

References:

- [Highcharts API reference for `allowDecimals`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.allowDecimals).